# jQuery's trigger method doesn't work properly on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some functionality that changes an HTML element based on the choice of the `radio` input, and that's working fine. However, for the initial setup of the element, instead of duplicating the conditioning and the code again, it would be much shorter and clearer to just invoke the `radio`'s `trigger('change')` method which then does all the work. This doesn't seem to work properly (in Firefox or Chrome). As much as I figure, it always treats the last `radio` in the document as the checked one.

A sample is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jydf5gby/

The initial color of the button should be red, but it comes up as blue. Why is that, and what is the solution?

HTML:

```
<p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="red" checked="checked"/> red</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="blue"/> blue</p>

<button>button</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=radio]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'red') {
            $('button').css('background', 'red');
        } else {
            $('button').css('background', 'blue');
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: You're triggering the event on all the radio buttons, not just the selected one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect selector to target checked radio button value after triggering change event. you need to use:

```
$('input[name=radio]').change(function () {
    if ( $('input[name=radio]:checked').val() == 'red') {
        $('button').css('background', 'red');
    } else {
        $('button').css('background', 'blue');
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b0dcyu7h/)**

**Update - Optimized Answer by Rory McCrossan**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[name=radio]').change(function () {
      $('button').css('background',  $('input[name=radio]:checked').val());
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

**[Demo for optimized code](http://jsfiddle.net/beza7byn/)**

Comment: Plus one, although you can also shorten this logic to remove the `if` statement: http://jsfiddle.net/b0dcyu7h/1/

Comment: Right... Thank you (have to wait 10 minutes before I can accept your answer).

Comment: @ImNotMike: yes. but his approach is best for situation you have provided.

Comment: Not sure how "optimized" this is, as you are searching the whole document for the checked radio button again, when you already have it in `this`, and on doc ready, testing it for every single radio on the screen.

Comment: i was talking about setting background value.

Answer (score 1):

You're triggering the event on all the radio buttons, not just the selected one. Try:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=radio]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'red') {
            $('button').css('background', 'red');
        } else {
            $('button').css('background', 'blue');
        }
    }).filter(":checked").trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="red" checked="checked"/> red</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="blue"/> blue</p>

<button>button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=radio]').change(function () {
        $('button').css('background', $('input[name=radio]:checked').val());
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8f521hj/)

---

As you are triggering the event applied on the `radio` inputs so you can just apply the values of those radios directly as i put in the answer. This makes your code a bit smaller and you can save a bit of bytes.

Comment: great! this deserves -1 without commenting anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling trigger for *all* the radio buttons. You just need to [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) them to the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=radio]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'red') {
            $('button').css('background', 'red');
        } else {
            $('button').css('background', 'blue');
        }
    }).filter(':checked').trigger('change');
});
```

[See Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jydf5gby/1/)

You can also optimize your actual handler to just set the background-color to the current val():

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=radio]').change(function () {
        $('button').css('background', $(this).val());
    }).filter(':checked').trigger('change');
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jydf5gby/2/)

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    
   
    $('input[name=radio]').bind("change",function(){
         if ($(this).val() == 'red') {
            $('button').css('background', 'red');
        } else {
            $('button').css('background', 'blue');
        }
    });
    $('input[name=radio]:first').click();
    
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="red" /> red</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="radio" value="blue"/> blue</p>

<button>button</button>
```